# error 404 on angular application with proxy redirection

Tags: angular, spring-boot, httpclient, http-proxy

I am developping an angular spring boot application.

I make the following request

```
  getListProduitImmobilierDTO(pagesize: number, page: number, search: Search): Observable<ProduitImmobilierDTO[]> {
    const headerDict = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Accept-Charset': 'charset=UTF-8',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type'
    };

    const requestOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders(headerDict)
    };
    return this.http.get('/api/produitimmobilier/all/' + pagesize + '/' + page, requestOptions).pipe(map((jsonArray: any) =>jsonArray.map((jsonItem) => ProduitImmobilierDTO.fromJson(jsonItem))));
```

I redirect the request using proxy.config.json which is the following

```
{
  "/api/*": {

    "target":  {
       "host": "localhost",
       "protocol": "http:",
       "port": 8080
     },
    "secure": false,
     "changeOrigin": true,
     "logLevel": "info"
  }
}
```

and to launch the angular application, I use the following command

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.config.json
```

On the server side, I have the following spring boot controller:

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200", maxAge = 3600)
@RestController
@RequestMapping({"/api"})
public class ProduitImmobilierController {

    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProduitImmobilierController.class);

    @Autowired
    private ProduitImmobilierService produitImmobilierService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/produitimmobilier/all/{pageSize}/{page}",
    method = RequestMethod.GET,
    produces = {"text/plain;charset=UTF-8", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE},
    consumes = {"text/plain;charset=UTF-8", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public @ResponseBody List<ProduitImmobilierDTO> findAll(@PathVariable("pageSize") int pageSize, @PathVariable("page") int page){
        logger.info("CONTROLLER PRODUITIMMOBILIERSERVICE CA PASSE");
        return produitImmobilierService.findAll(pageSize, page);
    }
```

It used to work. I made a try to modify the request and after reversing, it didn't work anymore. I have the following error

```
An attempt to set a forbidden header has been blocked : Accept-Charset http.js:2346
Object { headers: {…}, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "http://localhost:4200/api/produitimmobilier/all/5/1", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/api/produitimmobilier/all/5/1: 404 Not Found", error: {…} }
```

Could you help me

Answer (score 0):

When using `Angular dev-server proxy`, `CrossOrigin` shouldn't be configured on the server, as `Angular dev-server proxy` simply takes the browser request at the same domain + port where your frontend application runs and then forwards that request to your backend API server, in your case all requests made to port `4200`are forwordeed to port `8080`.

You're trying to set  `'Accept-Charset'` header, but according MDN 
`'Accept-Charset'` header is `Forbidden header name`(A forbidden header name is the name of any HTTP header that cannot be modified programmatically)

In any case you shouldn't use `'Accept-Charset'` header as UTF-8 is now well-supported and the preferred character encoding. To guarantee better privacy through less configuration-based entropy, all browsers omit the Accept-Charset header: Internet Explorer 8+, Safari 5+, Opera 11+, Firefox 10+ and Chrome 27+ no longer send it.

Comment: Hi Rafi, I modify the things according to your comment, but I have still the 404 Not found error. How can I debug it